# Parsing YAML in Go : map in list

Tags: parsing, go, yaml

I'm trying to parse a yaml file for a small project I have.

The goal is to have the app's infos in a config file including the address to the serverfile in case it need to be updated. It is in a config file for easy "editability" purposes.

The main thing is that there are some connectivity tests to be done before the app really starts. I'm trying to parse that file.
It looks like this :

```
conf.yaml

app:
    version:    "1"
    name:       MySuperApp
    configLocation:   http://configaddress

test_url:
  -
    name:       siteName1
    url:        http://siteUrl1
  -
    name:       siteName2
    url:        http://siteUrl2
    proxy_port: 5678
```

I wrote the following, I can get what's in app: but not what's in test_url :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "path/filepath"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type AppInfo struct {
    Name    string  `yaml:"name"`
    Version string  `yaml:"version"`
}

type Config struct {
    App AppInfo `yaml:"app"`
}

type TestUrl struct {
    Name        string `yaml:"name"`
    Url         string `yaml:"url"`
    ProxyPort   string `yaml:"proxy_port,omitempty"`
}

type TestUrls struct {
    ATest []TestUrl `yaml:"test_url"`
}

func main() {
    filename, _     := filepath.Abs("./config/conf.yaml")
    yamlFile, err   := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var config Config
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, &config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var test TestUrls
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, &test)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Application : ", config.App.Name,"\nVersion : ", config.App.Version)

    fmt.Println(test)
}
```

As an output I get :

```
Application : MySuperApp
Version : 1
{[]}
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: given file and code runs pretty well here.
```Application :  MySuperApp 
Version :  1
{[{siteName1 http://siteUrl1 } {siteName2 http://siteUrl2 5678}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, it was quite stupid...

But it can help others.

Putting the values inside of " " solved the problem.
eg.

```
name:       "siteName1"
url:        "http://siteUrl1"
```